# Intercept LINQ execution against database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, linq

Thought of it many ways unable to find a proper way from where to start it.

Many `LINQ` gets executed from application written in various classes.

Globally I want intercept all those queries, which are running against a database.

I know `SQL` Profiler can do this but I want to get it in run time from `asp.net` application.

I am using `ASP.NET` using `VB` with `LINQ to SQL` classes(DBML).

Any suggestions from where to start from or code in `VB`(Preferred) or `C#`?

Regards

Comment: Do you know where all these LINQ queries are made from? Meaning, do you have access to all the classes making calls to your DB?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes I have access to all the classes making calls to DB

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question. You can use the [QueryInterceptor("your Table")] to create a method to log all access to this table. Something looks Query Analyzer.

you can find more information in this post.
[How can I implement Query Interception in a LINQ to Entities query? (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249473/how-can-i-implement-query-interception-in-a-linq-to-entities-query-c)

Comment: I think as per the link you provided and some google QueryInterceptor is a part of WCF. But I am not using this. @AFetter

Comment: Query Interceptor is part of .net